# GAE Configure for Django App

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Can someone please help me transition a django app into the Google App Engine (GAE)?  I would like to be abel to take all of the files in my django app and copy them to the GAE app.  However, I am not sure how the default files for the GAE should be configured.  How should main.py file look so that runs the django app like it was designed to do:

main.py

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
application: appname
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.3"

builtins:
- django_wsgi: on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a django app running on app engine. I followed this link to get it up and running. http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine. There were a lot of little changes in all of the config files compared to regular django. I now do not use django as i love app engine and hate django. Below are some of my file examples. Note in your question you have a webapp2 request handler, you wont use anything like that with django. It will be all of the normal view definitions as functions, not classes like app engine. If you decide to try this approach out, let me know how it goes.

This is what my app.yaml after i follow the link above.

```
application: app
version: production
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

libraries:
- name: django
  version: latest


handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: djangoappengine.deferred.handler.application
  login: admin

- url: /_ah/stats/.*
  script: djangoappengine.appstats.application

- url: /.*
  script: djangoappengine.main.application
```

my settings.py

```
# Initialize App Engine and import the default settings (DB backend, etc.).
# If you want to use a different backend you have to remove all occurences
# of "djangoappengine" from this file.
from djangoappengine.settings_base import *
import os

DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

# Activate django-dbindexer for the default database
DATABASES['native'] = DATABASES['default']
DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'dbindexer', 'TARGET': 'native'}
AUTOLOAD_SITECONF = 'indexes'

INSTALLED_APPS = (

    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'djangotoolbox',
    'autoload',
    'dbindexer',

    # djangoappengine should come last, so it can override a few manage.py commands
    'djangoappengine',
    )

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # This loads the index definitions, so it has to come first
    'autoload.middleware.AutoloadMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    )

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'context_processors.general'
    )


ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media'),

    )
```

main.py

```
import os,sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')

# Google App Engine imports.
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

# Force Django to reload its settings.
from django.conf import settings
settings._target = None

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
import django.core.signals
import django.db
import django.dispatch

# Log errors.
#import logging
#def log_exception(*args, **kwds):
#    logging.exception('Exception in request:')
#
#django.dispatch.Signal.connect(
#    django.core.signals.got_request_exception, log_exception)

# Unregister the rollback event handler.
django.dispatch.Signal.disconnect(
    django.core.signals.got_request_exception,
    django.db._rollback_on_exception)

def main():
    # Create a Django application for WSGI.
    application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

    # Run the WSGI CGI handler with that application.
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```